# what language Chinese or Japanese?

Tags: chinese

[image]

Can't describe, label on a box, don't even know which way is up.  Need language of this label, so I can get it translated, and translate image/language inside box, to figure out if contents are worth anything.  Thank you!

Comment: The thing is that Japanese language uses Chinese hieroglyphs, in other words - there is no such thing as Japanese hieroglyphs. Japanese also uses a few syllabic alphabets but there is nothing like that on you picture.
Thus, whether this is Chinese or Japanese can only be derived from some extra information.. And this will probably require a true expert. Let's hope one will see this question soon. Any additional info about this box that you can share?

Comment: Actually, you probably don't have to know the language to get it translated. These glyphs have the same meaning (roughly speaking) in both languages, just absolutely different pronunciation but that's out of your interest, as far as I undersand :) So try Chinese (which my gut feeling tells me it is).

Comment: There _are_ sch things as Japanese hieroglyphs, in Japanese they are called [kokuji](https://www.tofugu.com/japanese/kokuji/), "native characters."

Comment: @YellowSky True. I had finished reading a facinating book by V.M.Alpatov "Japan: language and culture" about half a year ago. Vaguely remember he mentioned *kokuji* among all the many japanese scripts... (the book is available for free on flibusta, btw. In Russian, of course).

Answer (score 1):

This is in a script known as the [Seal Script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seal_script). The four characters are, in Chinese readings,

- Jin 金 - Gold
- To be honest I'm not quite sure, but it looks like Simplified Chinese for gui 龜 (龟) - turtle. You can clearly see the traditional character for 'turtle' in the red stamp.
- Fa 發 - Multi-purpose verb, meaning something along the lines of 'get a lot of' here
- Cai 財 - money

'Fa cai' means getting rich. As for 'golden turtle', that could mean an actual gold turtle (everything from gold mooncakes to gold Mickey Mouses exist out there, so you shouldn't be surprised), or it could be a beetle - the Chinese word for *beetle* is 金龜子 *jinguizi*...

Comment: There is a turtle in the box for which this is the label!  Chinese Seal Script, got it, thanks.